# How to stop jquery UI slider handle from dragging to some extend

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Please check this image 
[image]

I want to stop the slider handler before and after 10 px as shown in the image. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/HF6Sm/)

```
$( '#slider' ).slider({
orientation: 'vertical',
stop: function() {
    console.log('stop');
} });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the values on `slide` event and see if it goes beyond or under what you want, then you assign your limit value and prevent further dragging. Like this:

```
slide: function(e, ui){
        //if value is under wanted limit, you set value to limit 
        //and return false which will stop dragging.
        if(ui.value < 0){
            $(this).slider('value', 0)
            return false
        }
        //same if you have an upper limit
        if(ui.value > 100){
            $(this).slider('value', 100)
            return false
        }

    }
```

Note that you'll have to play with your `max` and `min` to make it fit with your need.

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/HF6Sm/614/